# How to Consume list in jQuery

Tags: jquery, database

I have a service return as list how to I consume this in jQuery help me this

```
enter code here

public List<MyData> GetDetails()
{
    //Comment the below line if don't want to wait GetCtcDetails
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

    string Details = string.Empty;
    List<MyData> clientlst = new List<MyData>();
    try
    {

    con = new SqlConnection(ConString);
    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Clientname, Address,country FROM HTML5_Sample", con);

        con.Open();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        while (dr.Read())
        {
            MyData clients = new MyData();
            clients.clientname = (string)dr["clientname"];
            clients.address = (string)dr["address"];
            clients.country = (string)dr["country"];
            clientlst.Add(clients);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {

    }

    return clientlst;
}
```

My jQuery Code

Function getCars() {

```
enter code here


$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "AdvService.asmx/GetDetails",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
  alert("test");
    alert(data);
    var cars = data.d;
    $('#output').empty();
    $.each(cars, function(index, MyData) {
      $('#output').append('<p><strong>' + MyData.Clientname + ' ' +
                            MyData.Address + '</strong><br /> Year: ' +
                            MyData.country + '<br />Doors: ' +
                            MyData.Price + '</p>');

    });

  },

  failure: function(msg) {
    $('#output').text(msg);
  }
});
```

In my  alert(data); i get [object Object],[object Object],[object Object] in my database return  3 list data... can any give me idea how to display my list in UI

Comment: have you tried doing `console.log(data)` ?, if you're using chrome or firefox it gives you a better idea of the object you're dealing with

Answer (score 1):

try console.log(data);

also use a debugger to inspect how the returned json looks like e.g fiddler or firebug. you can try

<s>alert(data.d['country']);//not guaranteed as i dont know how the actual json looks like</s>

or

```
alert(data['country']);
```

lets assume your returned response looks like

```
var data ='[
    {
        "clientname":"john",
        "country":"USA"
    },
    {
        "clientname":"smith",
        "country":"canada"
    }
]';
```

in the success handler

```
var json=$.parseJSON(data);//parse the json not necessary if you have dataType:'json'

alert(json[0].clientname);//will alert john
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sfUHn/6/)

---

## [**DEMO2**](http://jsfiddle.net/sfUHn/19/)

Comment: Looking at the response both of those cases will throw `undefined` because he's returning an array (List from C#)

Comment: probably yes but without looking at the actual response it was a short in the dark

Comment: nice :), I think he can get it to work the example and using the log.

Comment: I can get results i am using asp.net 2.0 so i get error. so response instead of data.d.its working.here i need to do some validattion if get 4 record i need to split and show it in two div tag how can i do that?

Comment: [{"__type":"AdvService+MyData","clientname":"ABC Tech","address":"Chennai","country":"India"},{"__type":"AdvService+MyData","clientname":"GGG","address":"USA","country":"USA"},...more here i cant post full

Comment: I my DB have 100 record so i planed to do $('#output').append('<div class=cn_item selected><center style=vertical-align:middle><h2></h2>'+
                                MyData.clientname + '</center></div>'); i already have next prev jquery template with me in that it allow only 4 record per page for page need to open other div how to do this?

Comment: @lakshman updated the answer with another demo change the if condition to your will

Comment: my expectation i want all the 100 records.<div id=main><div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div></div> again <div id=main><div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div></div> again other more all in loop how to do this